# Echarts - How to draw combinational chart with different data values in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, charts, vuejs2, echarts

I am using Echarts to represent data in my VueJS application and have run into a problem wherein I need to draw an echart with multiple combinations. The problem is EChart expects that all the series objects has same number of values in data objects. Is it possible to let it work with different values?

My code:

```
series : [
        {
            z: -1, // optional, makes the yAxis' splitLines appear on top
            name:'联盟广告',
            type:'line',
        smooth: true,
        showSymbol: false,
        lineStyle: {
            width:0
        },
            areaStyle: {color: '#708090'},
            data:[170, 182, 161, 184, 160, 180, 165]
        },
        {
            z: -1, // optional, makes the yAxis' splitLines appear on top
            name:'邮件营销',
            type:'line',
        lineStyle: {
            width:0
        },
        smooth: true,
        showSymbol: false,
            areaStyle: {color: '#F3F3F3', opacity: 1},
            data:[120, 132, 111, 134, 110, 130, 115]
        },{
        data: [80, 92, 71, 84, 60, 85, 170, 183, 205, 255, 300],
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true
    }]
```

Here first 2 charts have 7 values and last one has 11. But Echrats only considers first 7 of the 11.

Comment: You've used `highcharts` label but your question is not related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add some category data to your `xAxis` object by setting `xAxis.data` to an array of length 11.

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
},
```

Then your ECharts component will automatically map that array on the category axis, allowing you to expand the limit to 11 instead of 7:
[image]